Fully homomorphic encryption textbook suggestion
I am looking for mathematics textbooks which include a rigorous introduction to fully homomorphic encryption and especially CKKS / TFHE algorithms at the level of Boneh and Shoup's A Graduate Course in Applied Cryptography. Unfortunately the related chapter in their book is not yet written and moreover it is hard to find anything but articles on the subject due to their discovery dates (very recent) but I require something more pedagogical than the published papers. In the absence on such material, lecture notes or PhD theses etc. would also be fine given that they are aimed at mathematicians rather than engineers and are written rigorously.
I don't know how to make my request less opinion-based, please let me know if there is anything else I can specify.

Hit this. Not exactly a mathematics textbook, though.

https://bookauthority.org/books/best-homomorphic-encryption-books
